# Need rand() and cursorr to generate different number

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, cursor

I know this code will generate same number for each row
because the update statement is for whole column and the loop just overwrite the last step, but how can I generate different numbers for each row and I don't have primary key and any kind of key?

```
declare @origCost float
declare table_cursor cursor for 
select cost from [dbo].[x]where cost  is not null
open table_cursor;
Fetch next from table_cursor into @origCost

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
 update [dbo].[x]

 set cost=@origCost* round(rand()+rand(),2) where  cost is not null
 Fetch Next from table_cursor into @origCost
END;
CLOSE table_cursor;
DEALLOCATE table_cursor;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below query..

```
WITH cte_data 
AS (
SELECT cost,(cost*round(rand()+rand(),2)origCost
FROM [dbo].[x])
UPDATE a
SET a.cost=a.origCost
FROM cte_data a
```

if you need different numbers for calculation use the below script

```
WITH cte_data 
AS (
SELECT cost,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY cost)*(cost)origCost
FROM [dbo].[x])
UPDATE a
SET a.cost=a.origCost
FROM cte_data a
```

Comment: there is not id in the table

Comment: But  row number is  not kind of random number ,

Comment: for random value use 'SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(newID()))'

Answer (score 1):

To get random decimal within 0..2 use  `CAST (ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 200 /100. AS DECIMAL(3,2))` instead of `round(rand()+rand(),2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @origCost float
declare table_cursor cursor for 
select cost from [dbo].[x]where cost  is not null
open table_cursor;
Fetch next from table_cursor into @origCost

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
 update [dbo].[x]

 set cost=@origCost* round(rand()+rand(),2) where  cost is not null
 Fetch Next from table_cursor into @origCost
END;
CLOSE table_cursor;
DEALLOCATE table_cursor;
```

declare one variable.. with xxxxxxxxx value.. + randome no....
for each statement +1;